# Data.Set : does it always know best?

Tags: haskell

I need to represent a set and I'm starting to work with Data.Set.  I see that there's nothing to do really - `singleton`, `union`, `intersection`, etc. are all just there.  I like it.  I can express "what", not "how".  But my inner C programmer is uncomfortable.  There are many ways to implement a set (binary tree, hash, boolean array, etc.)  Can I really trust Data.Set to choose the best one?  Can I guide it in some way, or do I just surrender to its (I admit, probably superior) judgement?

Comment: Go with option 2, especially if this is for use in production code.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`Data.Set` has no inner intelligence (just see [the source](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/containers/0.4.2.1/doc/html/src/Data-Set.html#Set)!).  It is just a balanced tree or ordered elements.  You can look around on hackage for many other set and set-like structures with different performance characteristics.  For example, see [unordered-containers](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/unordered-containers) (HashSet), [HashTables](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hashtables) and [bloomfilter](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/bloomfilter).

Comment: OK, thanks.  I guess a follow-up question is - is there, or will there ever be, a `Data.Set` that can be trusted to make some of these implementation choices for the caller?  i.e. upon being told that the domain is just [1..8], it will figure out that it can just use a byte?

Comment: Seeing as the values are all boxed, you won't be able to make it use just a byte.  How would you implement that in Haskell?  I guess you'd check the value of the input and set the bit in your `Word8` manually then have to allocate a boxed value for every lookup?  Doesn't sound like a performance win to me.

Comment: Seems like you could still do set equality comparisons without any allocations, and perhaps unions and intersections with just one allocation of a Word8.

Comment: @gcbenison: Right, for some reason I was thinking of a map/lookup operation not a set/membership.  If you think you can make a set implementation that can intelligently pick representations then I'd encourage you to do it, benchmark it, talk to the community, polish the API, and upload to Hackage.  There is still plenty of low-hanging fruit in this community, it's just that for Haskell "low-hanging" has graduated from "weekend project" to "months long of moderate to serious effort".

Comment: @gcbenison Don't forget that GHC sometimes optimizes these things away anyway.

Answer (score 19):

The general `Data.Set` uses a balanced binary tree.  If you have sets of integers or bit vectors, you'll want `Data.IntSet`, which uses Patricia tries.

Both implementations have been honed through *years* of competition to get the best performance possible with Haskell.

Surrender  Dorothy!

Comment: This combined with Thomas's answer together form a fine answer.  `Data.Set` is great, has a wonderful interface, and is fast enough in most cases (much better than what any of us could roll by hand), but (like all things) it will not solve every problem optimally.  Don't worry about it until you need to; when you do, check out some of the other libraries.

Comment: @luqui I think when you have sets of integers it's worth going straight to `Data.IntSet`.